# Guardar primera palabra un archivo en c

Tags: c, archivo

Tengo un problema con esta parte de mi codigo, estoy intentando leer las lineas de un archivo y cortar solo la primera palabra de cada linea para posteriormente guardala en un arreglo.

La cuestion es que leo bien las lineas y con strtok corta la primera palabra y la mando a imprimir para verificar y todos bien hasta ahi, pero cuando mando guardar el resultado de strtok en el arreglo al final solo almacena la primera palabra del ultima renglon leido.

### Ejemplo:

> two roads diverged in a yellow wood
>
> and sorry i could not travel both
>
> and be one traveler long i stood
>
> and looked down one as far as i could
>
> to where it bent in the undergrowth

---

y como resultado yo espero un vector asi: "two, and, and, and, to"

pero me sale esto: "to, to, to, to, to"

Codigo:

```
dictionary *load_word(int autor, dictionary *D_first)
  {
   FILE *date;
   char line[LONG_MAX_LINE];
   char exeption[4] = " \n\t";
   char *word;
   int j=0;
   if (autor == 1)
   {
      if ((date = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL)
      {
         perror("robert_frost.txt");

      }
      while (fgets(line, LONG_MAX_LINE, date ) != "32")
      {   
         word = strtok(line, exeption); /*first word*/
         add_dictionary_first(D_first, j, word);
         j++;
      }

    fclose(date);
   }
   return D_first;  
 }
```

Comment: Sin ver que hace `add_dictionary_first`, creo que cada vez que agregas word al diccionario lo que estás haciendo es agregar un puntero a `char` (es decir, el `char *word`). De esta forma, todos los elementos de tu diccionario apuntan a la palabra word y como este toma el valor "to", todos los punteros de tu diccionario muestran "to" ¿es posible?

Comment: Necesitamos saber... ¿Qué es el `dictionary *D_first`?

Comment: Osea que si de igual forma mando la funcion strtok como parametro directamente a la funcion add_dictionary_first, el puntero que me regresa la funcion sera el mismo para todos los elementos del diccionario o eso entendi

Comment: ¿ Ese código está bien copiado/pegado ? `fgets(line, LONG_MAX_LINE, date ) != "32"` deberia dejarte en el bucle para siempre.

Answer (score 1):

No se que hace tu función `add_dictionary_first`, tampoco sé si el resultado de `fgets` llega a ser igual que la dirección de la constante  `"32"`. Si lo que intentabas era guardar la primera palabra de cada línea, entonces debes saber que `strtok` retorna el mismo puntero siempre que se llama, por lo que si lees la primera linea y sacas la primera palabra, todo irá bien, pero luego lees otra línea y llamas a `strtok`, el contenido del puntero "anterior" queda con el contenido de la primera palabra de la última línea que se *partió* con `strtok`.

A todo esto, una de las soluciones es crear una copia de la cadena retornada por `strtok`, en las siguientes líneas:

```
while (fgets(line, LONG_MAX_LINE, date ) != "32") {   
  word = strtok(line, exeption); /*first word*/
  add_dictionary_first(D_first, j, word);
  j++;
}
```

Con las siguientes<sup>1</sup>:

```
/* ... while(fgets... { */

word = strtok(line, exeption);         /*first word*/
int len = strlen(word);                /* longitud de la primera palabra. */
char *tword = calloc(1, len + 1);      /* en caso de emergencia, memoria dinamica. */
memcpy(tword, word, len);              /* Clonamos el contenido del puntero de strtok */
add_dictionary_first(D_fird, j, word); /* Y por ultimo agregamos al diccionario. */
j++;

/* } // Final del while. */
```

Para lograr esto, debes hacer `#include` a los siguientes encabezados a tu archivo `.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Dentro de `stdlib.h` se encuentra `calloc` y otras, que son funciones que necesitas cuando trabajas con memoria dinámica. Recuerda al final del programa o cuando su ciclo de vida se acabe, llamar a `free` con cada bloque de memoria dinámica reservado con `malloc` o `calloc`.

El código completo sería este:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ... Otras funciones... */

dictionary *load_word(int autor, dictionary *D_first) {
  FILE *date;
  char line[LONG_MAX_LINE];
  char exeption[4] = " \n\t";
  char *word;
  int j=0;
  if (autor == 1) {
    if ((date = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
      perror("robert_frost.txt");
    }
    while (fgets(line, LONG_MAX_LINE, date ) != "32") {   
      word = strtok(line, exeption); /*first word*/
      int len = strlen(word); /* longitud de la cadena retornada por strtok */
      char *tword = calloc(1, len + 1); /* +1 en caso de emergencia, memoria dinamica. */
      memcpy(tword, word, len); /* Copiamos la cadena en la memoria reservada. */
      add_dictionary_first(D_first, j, word);
      j++;
    }
    fclose(date);
  }
  return D_first;  
}

/* ... Otras, otras funciones... */
```

Con eso ya deberías visualizar todas las *primeras* palabras de cada línea.

<sup>1</sup>: He escríto el código a pura cabeza, si no funciona, dejarme saber para arreglarlo.

Saludos!

Comment: "pero luego lees otra línea y llamas a strtok, el contenido del puntero "anterior" queda con el contenido de la primera palabra de la última línea que se partió con strtok." si este era el error, bueno no tanto ahi el error, ya que cambie la funcion add_dictionary_first() donde seguia enviando el puntero a la estructura y no la palabra.

Voy a probar lo que me comentas. Gracias.