# Leer .txt separado por comas y guardar en una Lista o apuntador a char en C

Tags: c

tengo una archivo en el cual tengo informacion de paises de esta manera: 
Mexico, Mexico Df, Felipe calderon, Peso mexicano
Otros pais, otra capital, el presidente, moneda
...etc

y quiero guardarlos en una variable para luego meterlo a una estructura, tengo esto

```
FILE *f;
f=fopen("mundo.txt", "r");

char pal[100];
memset(pal, '\0', 100);

int cont=0;
for(i=0; i<TAM; i++){

fgets(pal, 100,f); //leo la linea

char *pais, *capital, *presidente, *moneda, *idioma; //la separo con strtok
pais=strtok(pal, ","); 
capital=strtok(NULL, ",");
presidente=strtok(NULL, ",");
moneda=strtok(NULL, ",");
idioma=strtok(NULL, ",");

int aux=indices[i]; //obtengo unos indices para mi arreglo de Listas
if(NumElem(arreglo[aux]) == 0){
    //Ingreso los elementos en mi lista
    arreglo[aux]=cons(pais, capital, presidente, moneda, idioma, NULL);
}

printf(" \n");

}

fclose(f);
```

Cuando intento acceder a un elemento de mi arreglo todos llevan la misma linea con basura, ejemplo :  Zimbabwe  we  a re  olar de Zimbabwe  bwe

Mi estructura recibe char *elem;

Ojala se entienda mi mensaje, gracias

Comment: Así a primera vista no veo ningún error evidente. Te recomiento hacer `printf` de `pal`, `pais`, `capital`... tan pronto obtengas los valores para ver dónde empiezan a tener valores inesperados, y así acotas el problema.

Comment: ¿Qué es `arreglo`? ¿y qué hace exactamente `cons`?

Comment: Hola, arreglo es un arreglo de Listas enlazadas, cons recibe los apuntadores a char y construye las Listas, el problema que tengo es cuando leo el archivo e imprimo pal, pais, capita etc me sale correcto pero después solo se guarda el ultimo elemento del archivo en todas las posiciones.

Comment: Si no has resuelto este problema, te dejo un enlace que puede serte útil: [Guardar primera palabra un archivo en c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131947/4499).